GCP conditional IAM binding for a Service Account Admin role
I want my Service Account (SA) to be able to only Disable other SA's.
Is that currently possible to have a conditional binding that will limit my SA to have only one or two permissions from the role Service Account Admin available? I know I can limit conditionally which SA's will be editable (by making a condition on the name of SA), so I'm looking for similar solution in CEL.
example:
SA: the-decativator@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com will be in charge of other SA's in the folder. It will have Service Account Admin role assigned folder level. Hopefully  some kind of the limitation applied, because I don't want this SA to create, update or remove other SA's from within this folder projects.
